# How to prevent hard-coding in angular application

Tags: angularjs

I am currently working on a angular project where I find myself injecting hard-coded values of string, numbers, etc into html template.I have tried to store  hard-coded values in object fields and inject the object into whichever component needs it. However it does not seem very intuitive. Is there way to get values from some properties file like we do in Java. I would also like to know what are some of the best practices that you developers are using to prevent that?

Comment: it's not really on-topic for SO, but I would say you either get data from a service, or create a small factory that returns the on to go values, which could easily be refactored at a later stage. If you would show some of the code where  you have problems with, it might be appropriate here, if you have a working solution and you want some input, you might rather check codereview :)

Comment: I guess you can name these hard-coded values as constants. In AngularJS you can write them as `app.constant('NAME', {"value":"data"})`, which then can be injected like any other provider (factory/service)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a properties file as well. The best way would be to create a json file, e.g., `example.json` and calling in the json and then just making an API call like:

```
$http.get('your_web_address/example.json')
.success(function(data){
 // assign the data to a var or write next logic directly
})
```

and then use the content of json as per choice

You can make this as a service call as well, if you want